# itcl tabnotebook missing tabs on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, tcl, itcl

I have a itcl/tk application that runs fine on Linux (and for the most part on Windows too). Have a frame where I packed an iwidgets::scrolledframe and within that an iwidgets::tabnotebook where two tabs were added.

Never have a problem on Linux, but on Windows (using Win7) often the 2nd tab is missing. Sometimes exiting and reinvoking the application on Windows and it will appear, but often it just never does. I have tried reorganizing code, inserted "update idletasks", to no avail.

Not sure if there are other tricks, or need to dig into itcl/tk installed code, or if could be a potentially a PC machine hardware issue.

Any ideas or suggestions of things to try will be graciously appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I appeared to resolve this via a strategically place update idletasks afterall. ;)